# Is mold on quartered artichokes bad?

Tags: artichokes

I found some dark mold on a bottle of quartered artichokes in the packing solution, and accidentally ate one before realizing there was a problem with them. Should I be worried?

Comment: Are you sure it was mold? Can you post a picture?

Comment: Indeed check if it is mold, seeing it *in* the solution is strange, usually mold appears on the surface (where water availability is higher). If the mold is *on the bottle* (i.e. at the outside), the contents haven't been in contact with the mold and should be ok. Usually mold induces off flavours as well.

Answer (score -5):

You shouldn't be very worried at the moment because mold usually isn't too harmful, and common symptoms are a stomach ache. If you feel worrying symptoms going to the doctor or the hospital (If necessary) may be a good idea. Still, keep in mind that it is rare to become very sick from eating mold and that you will probably be okay.

Comment: Danger depends on the mold and the growing conditions/substrate. Blue cheese has live molds, and is harmless, the same molds on bread are toxic. And some molds can be *very* toxic (aflatoxin in peanuts, ergot gungus on cereals).

Comment: That's what I was talking about, He didn't give any information and some mold can be dangerous.